# django object get two fields into a list from a model

Tags: python, django, django-models

this is my model

```
class pdUser(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Mobile = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    PagerDutyID = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    PagerDutyPolicyID = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    PagerDutyPolicy = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Want i want to be able to do is group by PagerDutyPolicy & PagerDutyPolicyID and return that as an object of its own with unique values only

so for example

```
Name: bob
PagerDutyPolicyID: 232
PagerDutyPolicy: Team 1

Name: Bill
PagerDutyPolicyID: 232
PagerDutyPolicy: Team 1

Name: Fred
PagerDutyPolicyID: 145
PagerDutyPolicy: Team 2
```

what i need is an object that has only got

```
PolicyID: 145
Policy: Team 2

PolicyID: 232
Policy: Team 1
```

in it, how would i do this?

Thanks

Comment: you have to create another model, and foreignKey this model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need two models, and a foreign key between them,  e.g.:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class PagerDutyPolicy(models.Model):
    # the model automatically gets an id field
    policy_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)  

class PagerDuty(models.Model):
    # I'm assuming you wanted these to be related to users who can log in..
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)   
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    policy = models.ForeignKey(PagerDutyPolicy)
```

To get all policies:

```
PagerDutyPolicy.objects.all()
```

To create a new `PagerDuty` object for bob, butting him in Team 1:

```
PagerDuty.objects.create(
    user=User.objects.get(username='bob'),  # or create a new user
    mobile='...',
    # policy=PagerDutyPolicy.objects.get(policy_name='Team 1')  # or..
    policy=PagerDutyPolicy.objects.get(id=232)
)
```

if you're going to look up policies by `policy_name` that field should also have a `db_index=True` in the model definition.

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

## get all (ID, Team) tuples, make unique

```
   id_teams = pdUser.objects.values_list('id', 'team', flat=True)
   id_teams = set(id_teams)
```

## turn into objects

```
   import collections
   IDTeam = collections.namedtuple('IDTeam', ['id', 'team'])
   output = [IDTeam(id=id, team=team)
             for id,team in id_teams]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine [values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#values) and [distinct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) methods like this:

```
pdUser.objects.all().values("PagerDutyPolicyID", "PagerDutyPolicy").distinct()
```

However this will produce fields with `PagerDutyPolicyID`, `PagerDutyPolicy` names